# What causes these print issues after changes on my Creality CP-01 extruder?

Tags: underextrusion, creality, overextrusion

I have a Creality CP-01 that has one of the feeders loose so I had to take down the entire extruder to fix it. After fixing it making sure it feeds properly and leveling the bed, it is producing what seems to be overflowing prints and I have no idea what to do to fix it.

I am working with the same nozzle I had used before and had to level the bed multiple times. No change in cura settings only the hardware.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. What's your actual question? I suggest changing the title into a question and if possibly adding more details about what it is you've changed exactly or what steps you took.

Comment: @BobOrtiz done this is the most i can provide i think

Comment: Previously the title described the issue, now it does not. Now it just says *when* "the issue" occurred (i.e. when the extruder was changed). I'm not sure if that is an improvement?